# Add an array to another array without index vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I ma creating a survey app in Vuejs.

I have this function to post the checked answers into my database :

```
postAnswerTest: function(modelId, topicId, questionId, answerId) {
      var finalAnswer = [];
      finalAnswer[questionId] = [modelId, topicId, questionId, answerId];
      this.finalArray.push(finalAnswer);
      console.log(this.finalArray);
    },
```

What I want is to insert finalAnswer array into finalArray array without creating a new index, because the index must be the questionId.

So I know the push method is not good, but I don't know how to do it.

Any idea?

Many thanks.

Comment: Would it be an option to use an object where the key is the `questionId` and holds the appropriate array instead of having an `array of arrays`?

Comment: if you need an array item to have a certain id, you might want to use an object instead of an array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that would be the code to my comment, not knowing if going with an object would be working for you...

```
postAnswerTest: function(modelId, topicId, questionId, answerId) {
    var finalAnswer = {modelId, topicId, questionId, answerId};
    this.finalObject[questionId] = finalAnswer;
    console.log(this.finalObject);
  },
```

Comment: Yes it could be a good solution, I'm going to see if I can use this array of objects for the next function of my app. Thank you!

Comment: if you are having trouble getting back the questionIds: You can get an array of the questionIds by `const questionIds = Object.keys(this.finalObject);`

Comment: I managed to obtain what I wanted with you first solution, it's perfect! Thanks again